# Problem when scraping data from webpage. Ruby on rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, watir

I'm developing a web-scraper. So, I wrote some code and don't understand why the loop doesn't work? How can help me with that?

scraper_service.rb:

```
browser = Watir::Browser.new
 browser.goto('some_link_here')

 browser.is(class: /event--head-block/).each do |event|
    event.is(class: /event--more/).button.click
    puts "Hello world"
    binding.pry
 end
```

So, when I executed the code, I didn't see 'hello world' in the console. In addition, when tried to understand are the class 'event--head-block' present on the web-page, I run `browser.element(class: /event--head-block/).exists?` and that returns true.

### Update

I forget to say that there are 8-10 same classes with name 'event--head-block'. Probably it's the reason?

Comment: What is the tag name of the element you want to match? If `browser.element(class: /event--head-block/).exists?` returns true and `browser.is(class: /event--head-block/)` is not finding anything, does that mean your element isn't an `<i>`?

Comment: @JustinKo tag element name is `<li>`. That's why I'm asking. So strange

Comment: If it's an `<li>`, it should be `#lis` not `#is`.

Comment: @JustinKo thanks, that's work, but could you please tell me how it works and why should we use `#lis`, if the element, for example, will be `<div>` the result should be `#divs`?

Comment: That's just how the Watir API was designed. For each element type there is a corresponding method that returns that element type. I have previously written some stuff about the different methods - https://leanpub.com/watirways/read#leanpub-auto-element-type. Maybe that will help clarify.